# Cannot find jndi data source

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, jndi

I tried to move my J2EE project in netbeans from windows to linux. My project function in windows but when I launch it in Ubuntu it gives me

```
"Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jndi_ubuntu__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: 
Invalid resource : jndi_ubuntu__pm"
```

I created the data source **jndi_ubuntu** but I go to 
Services -> Servers -> Glassfish -> Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Resources 
I can't see it!!
It looks like that I create new Data Sources but it doesn't see them.

`persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit name="csm-catering-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA"> 
 <jta-data-source>jndi_ubuntu</jta-data-source> 
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> 
 <properties/> 
</persistence-unit>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What? Are you trying to tell us that you have no datasource in your GlassFish and you expect that it can find a datasource?

Comment: There is not the data source jndi_ubuntu that I created under Resources.

Comment: Ur application is trying to connect datasource named jndi_ubuntu__pm. Have u created this datasource in GlassFish?

Comment: I created it going in my percistence.xml file and selecting Data Source: -> New Data Source..

Comment: How you have defined in your persistence.xml? Can you copy/paste here

Comment: <persistence-unit name="csm-catering-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jndi_ubuntu</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>

Answer (score 0):

According to error, application is trying to connect the datasource named **jndi_ubuntu__pm** and not **jndi_ubuntu** .You need to modify the jta-data-source tag in persistence.xml in order to match the dataSource JNDI name:

```
<jta-data-source>jndi_ubuntu__pm</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: I think is not so simple the solution

Comment: You can give it a try

Comment: Same error?Also what's the JNDI name of the JDBC Resource as you can see in GlassFish admin console (browse (localhost:4848))?

Comment: I don't understand what I must see

Comment: the command is `glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-jdbc-resources`, at least on Ubuntu.  You can also just do `glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin` and then run various commands.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved modifying file domain.xml in HOME/GLASSFISH/CONFIG/DOMAINS/DOMAIN1 like in the same file on Windows.